# F#: This expression was expected to have type DateTime but here has type unit

Tags: f#

The below F# function does not compile

```
open System
let checkCreation time : DateTime = 
    if (time > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7.0)) then printfn "New"
    else printfn "Old"

checkCreation time
```

The error markers point to "New" and to "Old"

The compiler fails with the following error:

> Script1.fsx(3,59): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
>
> ```
> DateTime
> ```
>
> but here has type
>
> ```
> unit
> ```

Why does the compiler expect a DateTime when I'm just trying to print something via printfn?

Comment: You can remove `: DateTime` from the method signature and let the compiler infer the types for you. Currently because of it compiler thinks that you are going to return `DateTime` from the function. But you are not returning anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace this

```
let checkCreation time: DateTime =
```

with this

```
let checkCreation (time: DateTime) =
```

First one has signature `(DateTime -> DateTime)` because you explicitly made this constraint to function output. Input has been inferred by compiler.

Second one has signature `(DateTime -> unit)`. Input has been explicitly constrained, and output `unit` inferred

Added:

Full explicit signature should look like this

```
let checkCreation (time: DateTime) : unit = 
    ...
```

You could delete every explicit type constraint and make compiler do the work:

```
//because time argument compared to DateTime it is inferred to be DateTime
//No explicit constrain needed
let checkCreation time = //DateTime -> unit

    //because if expression is the last one, its output will be used as function output
    if (time > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7.0))
    //because then branch has unit output, function output will be inferred as unit
    then printfn "New" 
    //else branch output MUST match with then branch. Your code pass :)
    else printfn "Old"
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Do I understand correctly that without the parentheses the `: DateTime` refers to the return value? And with them, it refers to the input argument?

Comment: @urig I've added some explanations

Comment: @urig I'm also relatively new to F#. I've found that it is best to first let the compiler try to figure out the types on its own and only add explicit annotations if it fails. (And I think that many more experienced people would agree with this.)

Comment: @urig It also helps to know that spaces (or any kind of juxtaposition) denoting function application has the highest precedence, over all binary operators including `:`, which is why the compiler parses your code roughly as `(checkCreation time): DateTime` if you omit parentheses.